# Can magically sharp swords like a vorpal sword cut stoneskin?

Tags: magic-items, adnd-2e

If someone is under the effect of the spell *stoneskin*, can a vorpal sword or a sword of sharpness bypass the protection afforded by the *stoneskin*?

One consideration is that both types of sword can cut through stone and enchanted stone creatures like stone golems.

Comment: You should accept the answer below, or comment on why it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 14):

**No.** The spell *stoneskin* (PHB p. 163) says in no uncertain terms that the target of the spell is completely immune to physical attacks, specifically including magically-enhanced physical attacks such as from a *sword of sharpness*. The *vorpal sword*'s description even says that it is just like the *sword of sharpness*, except with a better bonus.

The way to understand it is: if the damage is done by physical force in any way, the attack has no effect. If it's "magical energy" that does the damage, then *stoneskin* provides no protection.